# JSHint flags most of gulpfile.js as having undefined variable errors

Tags: javascript, gulp, jshint

I have what I believe is a fairly typical gulpfile.js.  When I open the file in Sublime or Atom with the jshint plugins enabled, it complains as in the below screenshot.  Essentially, all of the variable declarations are flagged as "undefined".  What's the setting in jshint to disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are defining them, but you are not. Look at your first few definitions:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  usemin = require('gulp-usemin'); // <-- HERE
  sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
// etc.
```

The `usemin` definition line ends in a semicolon **;** and not a comma **,** so all of the rest are not defined. I think you meant to do:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  usemin = require('gulp-usemin'), // <-- HERE
  sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
// etc.
```

Comment: We have all spent way too many hours finding little ones like that. :-) If someone wrote a jshint extension that actually figured out what we *meant* to do by reading our minds, I would pay good money for that!